# Color coding categories on a Sharepoint 2010 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar

Was wondering if someone has experience coloring a calendar event based on the value of a category.  I have seen guides to do this via Sharepoint Designer but would like a way to do this through the Visual Studio 2010 project that is creating the list.  Details or a link are most appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS, javascript & calculated columns should do the trick. Read the following post:

- [Tutorial: add color coding to your SharePoint 2007 calendar in 15 minutes](https://web.archive.org/web/20141208142551/http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/06/tutorial-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-2007-calendar-in-15-minutes/#6)

Comment: Use the first link and make sure you follow their recommendations for adding color to a Sharepoint 2010 calendar (needs a difference script).  Other than that this works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is through the calendar overlays feature. Create a view for each category. Then create a view that displays nothing (filter by date or something that excludes everything). Then add an overlay for each category view.

Comment: Here is one example of using the overlays programmatically: http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/06/programmatically-setting-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlays/

Answer (score 1):

Try this article on how to create a color coded calendar by category using JS in SharePoint 2010- 
http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2012/09/02/creating-a-color-coded-calendar-by-category-using-js-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Please try to provide more details to your answer, to make it more stand-alone from the link. The link may break before this page does :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make the Category display in one of the calendar mapped fields and add a CSS stylesheet either via Content Editor web part (one-off) or a CustomAction/DelegateControl (reusable).

Provided a week or day view has subheadings displaying the category, a style that will be supported by most modern browsers is as follows:

```
[title*=Warning].ms-acal-item {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow
}
[title*=Critical].ms-acal-item {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: red
}
```